# Python: How to get cube to spin and move in OpenGL Superbible example

Tags: python, numpy, opengl, pyopengl

For some reason, the cube does not move around the screen, though it spins.

This is with the use of the functions `m3dTranslateMatrix44` and `m3dRotationMatrix44` though there seems a better way.

Modified **`rotation_matrix(axis, theta)`** to produce a 4x4 matrix hopefully correctly.

I think perhaps it may be to create a `mv_matrix` through the use of numpy multiplication.  Done that.  But still off a bit.

Update - June 24, 2019: After some explanation and excellent code by Rabbid76 the program is now working as intended.  There is rotation and moving around the screen of the cube.  Very nice!

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import sys

import time
import math
fullscreen = True

# sys.path.append("../shared")

# from math3d import m3dDegToRad, m3dRotationMatrix44, M3DMatrix44f, m3dLoadIdentity44, \
                                            # m3dTranslateMatrix44, m3dScaleMatrix44, \
                                            # m3dMatrixMultiply44, m3dTransposeMatrix44, \
                                            # m3dRadToDeg

import numpy.matlib 
import numpy as np 

try:
    from OpenGL.GLUT import *
    from OpenGL.GL import *
    from OpenGL.GLU import *
    from OpenGL.raw.GL.ARB.vertex_array_object import glGenVertexArrays, \
                                                  glBindVertexArray
except:
    print ('''
    ERROR: PyOpenGL not installed properly.
        ''')
    sys.exit()

from math import cos, sin
from array import array

M3D_PI = 3.14159265358979323846
M3D_PI_DIV_180 = M3D_PI / 180.0
M3D_INV_PI_DIV_180 = 57.2957795130823229

# Translate matrix. Only 4x4 matrices supported
def m3dTranslateMatrix44(m, x, y, z):
    m[12] += x
    m[13] += y
    m[14] += z

def m3dDegToRad(num):
    return (num * M3D_PI_DIV_180)

def m3dRadToDeg(num):
    return (num * M3D_INV_PI_DIV_180)

def m3dOrtho(l, r, t, b, n, f):
    return (GLfloat * 16)(
        2/(r-l),      0,            0,            0,
        0,            2/(t-b),      0,            0,
        0,            0,            -2/(f-n),     0,
        -(r+l)/(r-l), -(t+b)/(t-b), -(f+n)/(f-n), 1)

def m3dPerspective(fov_y, aspect, n, f):
    a = aspect
    ta = math.tan( fov_y / 2 )
    return (GLfloat * 16)(
        1/(ta*a),  0,     0,              0,
        0,         1/ta,  0,              0,
        0,         0,    -(f+n)/(f-n),   -1,
        0,         0,    -2*f*n/(f-n),    0)

# Creates a 4x4 rotation matrix, takes radians NOT degrees
def m3dRotationMatrix44(m, angle, x, y, z):
    s = sin(angle)
    c = cos(angle)
    mag = float((x * x + y * y + z * z) ** 0.5)

    if mag == 0.0:
        m3dLoadIdentity(m)
        return

    x /= mag
    y /= mag
    z /= mag

    xx = x * x
    yy = y * y
    zz = z * z
    xy = x * y
    yz = y * z
    zx = z * x
    xs = x * s
    ys = y * s
    zs = z * s
    one_c = 1.0 - c

    m[0] = (one_c * xx) + c
    m[1] = (one_c * xy) - zs
    m[2] = (one_c * zx) + ys
    m[3] = 0.0

    m[4] = (one_c * xy) + zs
    m[5] = (one_c * yy) + c
    m[6] = (one_c * yz) - xs
    m[7] = 0.0

    m[8] = (one_c * zx) - ys
    m[9] = (one_c * yz) + xs
    m[10] = (one_c * zz) + c
    m[11]  = 0.0

    m[12] = 0.0
    m[13] = 0.0
    m[14] = 0.0
    m[15] = 1.0

def m3dMultiply(A, B):
    C = (GLfloat * 16)(*identityMatrix)
    for k in range(0, 4):
        for j in range(0, 4):
            C[k*4+j] = A[0*4+j] * B[k*4+0] + A[1*4+j] * B[k*4+1] + \
                       A[2*4+j] * B[k*4+2] + A[3*4+j] * B[k*4+3]
    return C

def translate(tx, ty, tz):
    """creates the matrix equivalent of glTranslate"""
    return np.array([1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 
                     0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 
                     0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 
tx, ty, tz, 1.0], np.float32)

def rotation_matrix(axis, theta):
    """
    Return the rotation matrix associated with counterclockwise rotation about
    the given axis by theta radians.
    """
    axis = np.asarray(axis)
    axis = axis / math.sqrt(np.dot(axis, axis))
    a = math.cos(theta / 2.0)
    b, c, d = -axis * math.sin(theta / 2.0)
    aa, bb, cc, dd = a * a, b * b, c * c, d * d
    bc, ad, ac, ab, bd, cd = b * c, a * d, a * c, a * b, b * d, c * d
    return np.array([[aa + bb - cc - dd, 2 * (bc + ad), 2 * (bd - ac), 0],
                     [2 * (bc - ad), aa + cc - bb - dd, 2 * (cd + ab), 0],
                     [2 * (bd + ac), 2 * (cd - ab), aa + dd - bb - cc, 0],
[0,0,0,1]])

identityMatrix = [1,0,0,0, 0,1,0,0, 0,0,1,0, 0,0,0,1]

mv_location = (GLfloat * 16)(*identityMatrix)
proj_location = (GLfloat * 16)(*identityMatrix)
proj_matrix = (GLfloat * 16)(*identityMatrix)

many_cubes = False

# Vertex program
vs_source = '''
    #version 410 core                                                  
    in vec4 position;                                                  
    out VS_OUT                                                         
    {                                                                  
        vec4 color;                                                    
    } vs_out;                                                          
    uniform mat4 mv_matrix;                                            
    uniform mat4 proj_matrix;                                          
    void main(void)                                                    
    {                                                                  
        gl_Position = proj_matrix * mv_matrix * position;              
        vs_out.color = position * 2.0 + vec4(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.0);      
    }                                                                  
'''

# Fragment program
fs_source = '''
    #version 410 core                                                  
    out vec4 color;                                                    
    in VS_OUT                                                          
    {                                                                  
        vec4 color;                                                    
    } fs_in;                                                           
    void main(void)                                                    
    {                                                                  
        color = fs_in.color;                                           
    }                                                                  
'''


def compile_program(vertex_source, fragment_source):

    global mv_location
    global proj_location

    vertex_shader = None
    fragment_shader = None

    if vertex_source:

        vertex_shader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER)
        glShaderSource(vertex_shader, vertex_source)
        glCompileShader(vertex_shader)

        if not glGetShaderiv(vertex_shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS):
                    raise Exception('failed to compile shader "%s":\n%s' % 
                    ('vertex_shader', glGetShaderInfoLog(vertex_shader)))

    if fragment_source:

        fragment_shader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER)
        glShaderSource(fragment_shader, fragment_source)
        glCompileShader(fragment_shader)

        if not glGetShaderiv(fragment_shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS):
                    raise Exception('failed to compile shader "%s":\n%s' % 
                    ('fragment_shader', glGetShaderInfoLog(fragment_shader)))

    program = glCreateProgram()

    glAttachShader(program, vertex_shader)
    glAttachShader(program, fragment_shader)

    glLinkProgram(program)

    mv_location = glGetUniformLocation(program, "mv_matrix");
    proj_location = glGetUniformLocation(program, "proj_matrix");

    vao = GLuint(0)
    glGenVertexArrays(1, vao);
    glBindVertexArray(vao);

    vertex_positions = [
        -0.25,  0.25, -0.25,
        -0.25, -0.25, -0.25,
         0.25, -0.25, -0.25,

         0.25, -0.25, -0.25,
         0.25,  0.25, -0.25,
        -0.25,  0.25, -0.25,

         0.25, -0.25, -0.25,
         0.25, -0.25,  0.25,
         0.25,  0.25, -0.25,

         0.25, -0.25,  0.25,
         0.25,  0.25,  0.25,
         0.25,  0.25, -0.25,

         0.25, -0.25,  0.25,
        -0.25, -0.25,  0.25,
         0.25,  0.25,  0.25,

        -0.25, -0.25,  0.25,
        -0.25,  0.25,  0.25,
         0.25,  0.25,  0.25,

        -0.25, -0.25,  0.25,
        -0.25, -0.25, -0.25,
        -0.25,  0.25,  0.25,

        -0.25, -0.25, -0.25,
        -0.25,  0.25, -0.25,
        -0.25,  0.25,  0.25,

        -0.25, -0.25,  0.25,
         0.25, -0.25,  0.25,
         0.25, -0.25, -0.25,

         0.25, -0.25, -0.25,
        -0.25, -0.25, -0.25,
        -0.25, -0.25,  0.25,

        -0.25,  0.25, -0.25,
         0.25,  0.25, -0.25,
         0.25,  0.25,  0.25,

         0.25,  0.25,  0.25,
        -0.25,  0.25,  0.25,
        -0.25,  0.25, -0.25 ]

    buffer = GLuint(0)
    glGenBuffers(1, buffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer);

    #ar=numpy.array(vertex_positions, dtype='float32')
    ar=array("f",vertex_positions)
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, ar.tostring(), GL_STATIC_DRAW)

    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, None);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
    glFrontFace(GL_CW);

    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);

    return program


class Scene:

    def __init__(self, width, height):

        self.width = width
        self.height = height

    def display(self):
        global mv_location
        global proj_location
        global proj_matrix
        global many_cubes

        currentTime = time.time()

        green = [ 0.0, 0.25, 0.0, 1.0 ]
        one = 1.0;

        glViewport(0, 0, int((1360/2)-(512/2)), int((768/2)-(512/2)))


        glClearBufferfv(GL_COLOR, 0, green);
        glClearBufferfv(GL_DEPTH, 0, one);        

        glUseProgram(compile_program(vs_source, fs_source))

        #proj_matrix = m3dOrtho(-1, 1, -1, 1, -10, 10)
        #proj_matrix = m3dPerspective(50.0*math.pi/180.0, 512/512, 0.1, 1000.0)
        #proj_matrix = m3dPerspective(m3dDegToRad(50.0), float(self.width) / float(self.height), 0.1, 1000.0);

        glUniformMatrix4fv(proj_location, 1, GL_FALSE, proj_matrix)

        if (many_cubes == True):

            for i in range(0, 24):
                f = i + currentTime * 0.3;

                mv_matrix = (GLfloat * 16)(*identityMatrix)

                T = (GLfloat * 16)(*identityMatrix)
                m3dTranslateMatrix44(T, 0, 0, -4)

                W = (GLfloat * 16)(*identityMatrix)
                m3dTranslateMatrix44(W, sin(2.1 * f) * 0.5, cos(1.7 * f) * 0.5, sin(1.3 * f) * cos(1.5 * f) * 2.0)

                RX = (GLfloat * 16)(*identityMatrix)
                m3dRotationMatrix44(RX, currentTime * m3dDegToRad(45.0), 0.0, 1.0, 0.0)

                RY = (GLfloat * 16)(*identityMatrix)
                m3dRotationMatrix44(RY, currentTime * m3dDegToRad(81.0), 1.0, 0.0, 0.0)


                mv_matrix = m3dMultiply(W, m3dMultiply(T, m3dMultiply(RY, RX)))

                # or can multiply with numpy
                #R = np.matmul(np.array(W).reshape(4,4) , np.matmul(np.array(RX).reshape(4,4), np.array(RY).reshape(4,4)))
                #mv_matrix = np.matmul(R, np.array(T).reshape(4,4))


                # third way this could be done
                # T  = np.matrix(translate(0.0, 0.0, -4.0)).reshape(4,4)
                # W  = np.matrix(translate(sin(2.1 * f) * 0.5, cos(1.7 * f) * 0.5, sin(1.3 * f) * cos(1.5 * f) * 2.0)).reshape(4,4)
                # RX = np.matrix(rotation_matrix( [1.0, 0.0, 0.0], currentTime * m3dDegToRad(17.0)))
                # RY = np.matrix(rotation_matrix( [0.0, 1.0, 0.0], currentTime * m3dDegToRad(13.0)))
                # mv_matrix = RX * RY * T * W

                glUniformMatrix4fv(mv_location, 1, GL_FALSE, mv_matrix)

                glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 36)

        else:
            f = currentTime * 0.3;

            mv_matrix = (GLfloat * 16)(*identityMatrix)

            T = (GLfloat * 16)(*identityMatrix)
            m3dTranslateMatrix44(T, 0, 0, -4)

            W = (GLfloat * 16)(*identityMatrix)
            m3dTranslateMatrix44(W, sin(2.1 * f) * 0.5, cos(1.7 * f) * 0.5, sin(1.3 * f) * cos(1.5 * f) * 2.0)

            RX = (GLfloat * 16)(*identityMatrix)
            m3dRotationMatrix44(RX, currentTime * m3dDegToRad(45.0), 0.0, 1.0, 0.0)

            RY = (GLfloat * 16)(*identityMatrix)
            m3dRotationMatrix44(RY, currentTime * m3dDegToRad(81.0), 1.0, 0.0, 0.0)

            mv_matrix = m3dMultiply(W, m3dMultiply(T, m3dMultiply(RY, RX)))

            # second way to that can multiply with numpy
            #R = np.matmul(np.array(W).reshape(4,4) , np.matmul(np.array(RX).reshape(4,4), np.array(RY).reshape(4,4)))
            #mv_matrix = np.matmul(R, np.array(T).reshape(4,4))


            # third way this could be done
            # T  = np.matrix(translate(0.0, 0.0, -4.0)).reshape(4,4)
            # W  = np.matrix(translate(sin(2.1 * f) * 0.5, cos(1.7 * f) * 0.5, sin(1.3 * f) * cos(1.5 * f) * 2.0)).reshape(4,4)
            # RX = np.matrix(rotation_matrix( [1.0, 0.0, 0.0], currentTime * m3dDegToRad(17.0)))
            # RY = np.matrix(rotation_matrix( [0.0, 1.0, 0.0], currentTime * m3dDegToRad(13.0)))
            # mv_matrix = RX * RY * T * W


            glUniformMatrix4fv(mv_location, 1, GL_FALSE, mv_matrix)

            glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 36)

        glutSwapBuffers()

    def reshape(self, width, height):
        global proj_matrix
        proj_matrix = m3dPerspective(m3dDegToRad(50.0), float(self.width) / float(self.height), 0.1, 1000.0);

        self.width = width
        self.height = height

    def keyboard(self, key, x, y ):
        global fullscreen
        global many_cubes

        print ('key:' , key)
        if key == b'\x1b': # ESC
            sys.exit()

        elif key == b'f' or key == b'F': #fullscreen toggle

            if (fullscreen == True):
                glutReshapeWindow(512, 512)
                glutPositionWindow(int((1360/2)-(512/2)), int((768/2)-(512/2)))
                fullscreen = False
            else:
                glutFullScreen()
                fullscreen = True

        elif key == b'm' or key == b'M': 

            if (many_cubes == True):
                many_cubes = False
            else:
                many_cubes = True

        print('done')

    def init(self):
        pass

    def timer(self, blah):

        glutPostRedisplay()
        glutTimerFunc( int(1/60), self.timer, 0)
        time.sleep(1/60.0)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    start = time.time()

    glutInit()
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_DEPTH)

    glutInitWindowSize(512, 512)

    w1 = glutCreateWindow('OpenGL SuperBible - Spinny Cube')
    glutInitWindowPosition(int((1360/2)-(512/2)), int((768/2)-(512/2)))

    fullscreen = False
    many_cubes = False
    #glutFullScreen()

    scene = Scene(512,512)
    glutReshapeFunc(scene.reshape)
    glutDisplayFunc(scene.display)
    glutKeyboardFunc(scene.keyboard)

    glutIdleFunc(scene.display)
    #glutTimerFunc( int(1/60), scene.timer, 0)

    scene.init()

    glutMainLoop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression form the question:

> ```
> mv_matrix = np.array(A * B * C * D)
> ```

performs a component-wise multiplication of the elements of the [`numpy.array`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array.html).

A concatenation of matrices can be performed by [`numpy.matmul`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.matmul.html).

The operation

```
C = A * B
```

can be expressed as

```py
C = np.matmul(B, A)
```

So concatenate 4 matrices `A * B * C *  D` is:

```py
mv_matrix = np.matmul(D, np.matmul(C, np.matmul(B, A)))
```

Note, if you use [`numpy.matrix`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.html) rather than `numpy.array`, then the `*`-operator proceeds a matrix multiplication.

---

Side note: The identity matrix can be set by [`numpy.identity`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.identity.html)

```py
ident4x4 = np.identity(4, np.float32)
```

since the data-type of the output defaults to float, this can be simplified further:

```py
ident4x4 = np.identity(4)
```

---

e.g. Use the functions `translate` and `rotation_matrix` to concatenate a translation and rotations around the x and y axis:

```py
T  = np.matrix(translate(0.0, 0.0, -4.0)).reshape(4,4)
RX = np.matrix(rotation_matrix( [1.0, 0.0, 0.0], currentTime * m3dDegToRad(17.0)))
RY = np.matrix(rotation_matrix( [0.0, 1.0, 0.0], currentTime * m3dDegToRad(13.0)))

mv_matrix = RX * RY * T
```

Comment: having a problem with using the translate and rotation_matrix instead of the functions in the program that work, m3dTranslateMatrix44 and m3dRotationMatrix44.. No big deal.  Just wanted to try the abbreviated form mv_matrix=Rx*RY*T to check working.

Comment: Yes, it is working now.  Don't know why I was receiving error before.  This version is very nice as it has the 3 ways to matrix multiply there.  Thank You.  I am now beginning the porting of the ktx file format loader.  I'll post a Q. if any problem and even to get feedback on code.  I have to admit that the SBM file loader code is very nice, good use of OO, and numpy is a new favorite tool now for me, especially the way it converted 4 bytes to a single variable, that was impressive.  Thanks.

Comment: the code that not working is the second way  the sbm file format torus source code of course [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56711138/how-to-read-parse-the-sbm-file-format-from-superbible-opengl) that is commented out using m3dMultiply, perhaps you could take a look at it?  TY

Comment: @StanS. Matrix multiplication is not commutative. `m3dMultiply` works in the reverse order, the same way like matrix multiplications in [GLSL](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/) and [PyGLM](https://pypi.org/project/PyGLM/). In your code the translation is applied first an then the torus is rotated out of the view. It has to be  `R = m3dMultiply(RY, RX)` `mv_matrix = m3dMultiply(T, R)`.

Comment: Now it is working given the valuable insight and knowledge it not commutative, but particular to some order when multiplying matrices!  Though the workings of why of the pattern of the order not apparent to me at this time, though agreed 100% not commutative. Thank You.