# how to read, parse the SBM file format from Superbible Opengl

Tags: python, python-3.x, opengl, glut, fileparsing

Calling on experts, gurus, and anybody to help read and parse a file in python.

On page 751 of 6th ed. or page 800 of 7th ed. of Superbible OpenGL there is Appendix B. The SBM File Format that seems to explain well the format to some extent.

I have tried to implement in python a reader of this file format.

OK, progress has been made. I have merged Rabbid76 amazing code to the source provided.  Though I am attempting to make additional headway.

Update Jun 23, 2019 - major progress, fixed the error about glVertexAttribPointer(i, ...  error.

Same day, fixed the Python cannot find the variable **first** error.

Same day, SUCCESS!!!! We have something that renders!  Here is the final program [sbmloader.py](https://github.com/ohlogic/PythonOpenGLSuperBible7Glut/blob/master/chapt05/shared/sbmloader.py) that reads, parses the SBM file format, created from this question.

Though the next question.  Already answered, at [part 2, creation of a ktxloader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56749815/how-to-read-in-python-the-ktx-file-format-used-in-the-book-superbible-opengl-pa)

- How to get the rendered object to appear as the torus/donut it is supposed to be?  Perhaps there is something to do with loading the file here  [pattern1.ktx](https://github.com/ohlogic/PythonOpenGLSuperBible7Glut/blob/master/chapt05/pattern1.ktx)  How do I load this to the variable **tex_object** variable?  Simply assigning it doesn't seem to do anything.  Ok, that's because ktx files are a different file format left for another project.

Update: June 24, 2019
The rendering issue has been fixed with perfect code by Rabbid76.  I in wow shock, thank you very much!

The data to read, parse is here [torus_nrms_tc.sbm](https://github.com/nickhutchinson/SB6Python/blob/master/src/sb6/resources/torus_nrms_tc.sbm)

Any assistance, comments, or insight would be greatly appreciated. 
Here is what I have so far.

```
import sys
import time 
import os
import time
import math
import ctypes

currentWDir = os.getcwd()
print( 'current working directory: {}'.format( str(currentWDir) ) )
fileDir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) # det the directory of this file
print( 'current location of self: {}'.format( str(fileDir) ) )
parentDir = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(fileDir, os.pardir)) # get the parent directory of this file
sys.path.insert(0, parentDir)
print( 'insert system directory: {}'.format( str(parentDir) ) )
os.chdir( fileDir )
baseWDir = os.getcwd()
print( 'changed current working directory: {}'.format( str(baseWDir) ) )
print ( '' )

fullscreen = True

import numpy.matlib 
import numpy as np 

try:
    from OpenGL.GLUT import *
    from OpenGL.GL import *
    from OpenGL.GLU import *
    #from OpenGL.raw.GL.ARB.vertex_array_object import glGenVertexArrays, glBindVertexArray
except:
    print ('''
    ERROR: PyOpenGL not installed properly.
        ''')
    sys.exit()

def SB6M_FOURCC(a,b,c,d):
    return ( (ord(a) << 0) | (ord(b) << 8) | (ord(c) << 16) | (ord(d) << 24) )

SB6M_MAGIC = SB6M_FOURCC('S','B','6','M')

SB6M_CHUNK_TYPE_INDEX_DATA      = SB6M_FOURCC('I','N','D','X')
SB6M_CHUNK_TYPE_VERTEX_DATA     = SB6M_FOURCC('V','R','T','X')
SB6M_CHUNK_TYPE_VERTEX_ATTRIBS  = SB6M_FOURCC('A','T','R','B')
SB6M_CHUNK_TYPE_SUB_OBJECT_LIST = SB6M_FOURCC('O','L','S','T')
SB6M_CHUNK_TYPE_COMMENT         = SB6M_FOURCC('C','M','N','T')
SB6M_CHUNK_TYPE_DATA            = SB6M_FOURCC('D','A','T','A')

class SB6M_HEADER:
    def __init__(self, data):
        int_data = np.frombuffer(np.array(data[:16], dtype=np.byte), dtype=np.uint32)
        self.magic, self.size, self.num_chunks, self.flags = int_data 
        print(self.magic, self.size, self.num_chunks, self.flags)

class SB6M_CHUNK_HEADER:
    def __init__(self, data, offset):
        int_data = np.frombuffer(np.array(data[offset:offset+8], dtype=np.byte), dtype=np.uint32)
        self.type, self.size = int_data

class SB6M_CHUNK_INDEX_DATA(SB6M_CHUNK_HEADER):
     def __init__(self, data, offset):
        super().__init__(data, offset)
        int_data = np.frombuffer(np.array(data[offset+8:offset+20], dtype=np.byte), dtype=np.uint32)
        self.index_type, self.index_count, self.index_data_offset = int_data

class SB6M_CHUNK_VERTEX_DATA(SB6M_CHUNK_HEADER):
     def __init__(self, data, offset):
        super().__init__(data, offset)
        int_data = np.frombuffer(np.array(data[offset+8:offset+20], dtype=np.byte), dtype=np.uint32)
        self.data_size, self.data_offset, self.total_vertices = int_data

class SB6M_CHUNK_VERTEX_DATA(SB6M_CHUNK_HEADER):
     def __init__(self, data, offset):
        super().__init__(data, offset)
        int_data = np.frombuffer(np.array(data[offset+8:offset+20], dtype=np.byte), dtype=np.uint32)
        self.data_size, self.data_offset, self.total_vertices = int_data

SB6M_VERTEX_ATTRIB_FLAG_NORMALIZED = 0x00000001
SB6M_VERTEX_ATTRIB_FLAG_INTEGER    = 0x00000002

class SB6M_VERTEX_ATTRIB_DECL:
    def __init__(self, data, offset):
        self.name = ''.join([chr(n) for n in data[offset:offset+64] if n > 30])
        int_data = np.frombuffer(np.array(data[offset+64:offset+84], dtype=np.byte), dtype=np.uint32)
        self.size, self.type, self.stride, self.flags, self.data_offset = int_data

class SB6M_VERTEX_ATTRIB_CHUNK(SB6M_CHUNK_HEADER):
    def __init__(self, data, offset):
        super().__init__(data, offset)
        int_data = np.frombuffer(np.array(data[offset+8:offset+12], dtype=np.byte), dtype=np.uint32)
        self.attrib_count = int_data[0]
        self.attrib_data = []
        for i in range(self.attrib_count):
            self.attrib_data.append(SB6M_VERTEX_ATTRIB_DECL(data, offset+12+i*84))

class SB6M_DATA_CHUNK(SB6M_CHUNK_HEADER):
    def __init__(self, data, offset):
        super().__init__(data, offset)
        int_data = np.frombuffer(np.array(data[offset+8:offset+20], dtype=np.byte), dtype=np.uint32)
        self.encoding, self.data_offset, self.data_length = int_data

class SB6M_SUB_OBJECT_DECL:
    def __init__(self, data, offset):
        int_data = np.frombuffer(np.array(data[offset:offset+8], dtype=np.byte), dtype=np.uint32)
        self.first, self.count = int_data

class SB6M_CHUNK_SUB_OBJECT_LIST(SB6M_CHUNK_HEADER):
    def __init__(self, data, offset):
        super().__init__(data, offset)
        int_data = np.frombuffer(np.array(data[offset+8:offset+12], dtype=np.byte), dtype=np.uint32)
        self.count = int_data[0]
        self.sub_object = []
        for i in range(self.count):
            self.sub_object.append(SB6M_SUB_OBJECT_DECL(data, offset+12+i*8))

class SB6M_CHUNK_HEADER_:
    chunk_type = 0
    chunk_name = ''
    size = 0

class SB6M_DATA_ENCODING:
    SB6M_DATA_ENCODING_RAW  = 0


class SB6M_CHUNK_COMMENT:
    header = SB6M_CHUNK_HEADER_()
    comment = []
    comment.append('')
    comment.append('')


# data_buffer = GLuint(0)
# vao = GLuint(0)
# index_type = GLuint(0)
index_offset = GLuint(0)



def get_sub_object_info(index, first, count):
    if (index >= num_sub_objects):
        first = 0
        count = 0
    else:
        first = sub_object[index].first;
        count = sub_object[index].count;

def render(instance_count = 1, base_instance = 0):
    render_sub_object(0, instance_count, base_instance)


class SBMObject:

    def __init__(self):
        self.vao = GLuint(0)

    def load(self, filename):

        vertex_attrib_chunk = None
        vertex_data_chunk = None
        index_data_chunk = None
        sub_object_chunk = None
        data_chunk = None

        #try:
        data = numpy.fromfile(filename, dtype=np.byte)
        filesize = data.size

        header = SB6M_HEADER(data)
        offset = header.size

        for i in range(header.num_chunks):

            chunk = SB6M_CHUNK_HEADER(data, offset)
            if chunk.type == SB6M_CHUNK_TYPE_VERTEX_ATTRIBS:
                vertex_attrib_chunk = SB6M_VERTEX_ATTRIB_CHUNK(data, offset) 
            elif chunk.type == SB6M_CHUNK_TYPE_VERTEX_DATA:
                vertex_data_chunk = SB6M_CHUNK_VERTEX_DATA(data, offset)
            elif chunk.type == SB6M_CHUNK_TYPE_INDEX_DATA:
                index_data_chunk = SB6M_CHUNK_INDEX_DATA(data, offset) 
            elif chunk.type == SB6M_CHUNK_TYPE_SUB_OBJECT_LIST:
                sub_object_chunk = SB6M_CHUNK_SUB_OBJECT_LIST(data, offset)
            elif chunk.type == SB6M_CHUNK_TYPE_DATA:
                data_chunk = SB6M_DATA_CHUNK(data, offset) 
            else:
                raise

            offset += chunk.size

        #except:
        #    print("error reading file {}".format(filename))

        print("finished reading")

        if vertex_data_chunk and vertex_attrib_chunk:
            start = vertex_data_chunk.data_offset
            end = start + vertex_data_chunk.data_size
            vertex_data = np.frombuffer(np.array(data[start:end], dtype=np.byte), dtype=np.float)

            data_buffer = glGenBuffers(1)
            glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, data_buffer)
            glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertex_data, GL_STATIC_DRAW)

            self.vertexcount = vertex_data_chunk.total_vertices
            self.vao = glGenVertexArrays(1)
            glBindVertexArray(self.vao)

            for attrib_i, attrib in enumerate(vertex_attrib_chunk.attrib_data):
                if attrib.name=='position' or attrib.name=='map1': 
                    glVertexAttribPointer(attrib_i,
                        attrib.size, attrib.type,
                        GL_TRUE if (attrib.flags & SB6M_VERTEX_ATTRIB_FLAG_NORMALIZED) != 0 else GL_FALSE,
                        attrib.stride, ctypes.c_void_p(int(attrib.data_offset)))
                    glEnableVertexAttribArray(attrib_i)

    def render(self):

        glBindVertexArray(self.vao)
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, self.vertexcount)

# Vertex program
vs_source = '''
#version 420 core
uniform mat4 mv_matrix;
uniform mat4 proj_matrix;
layout (location = 0) in vec4 position;
layout (location = 4) in vec2 tc;
out VS_OUT
{
    vec2 tc;
} vs_out;
void main(void)
{
    vec4 pos_vs = mv_matrix * position;
    vs_out.tc = tc;
    gl_Position = proj_matrix * pos_vs;
}
'''

# Fragment program
fs_source = '''
#version 420 core
layout (binding = 0) uniform sampler2D tex_object;
in VS_OUT
{
    vec2 tc;
} fs_in;
out vec4 color;
void main(void)
{
    color = texture(tex_object, fs_in.tc * vec2(3.0, 1.0));
}
'''

identityMatrix = [1,0,0,0, 0,1,0,0, 0,0,1,0, 0,0,0,1]

render_prog = GLuint(0)

uniforms_mv_matrix = (GLfloat * 16)(*identityMatrix)
uniforms_proj_matrix = (GLfloat * 16)(*identityMatrix)

tex_index = 0
tex_object = []

M3D_PI = 3.14159265358979323846
M3D_PI_DIV_180 = M3D_PI / 180.0
M3D_INV_PI_DIV_180 = 57.2957795130823229

def m3dDegToRad(num):
    return (num * M3D_PI_DIV_180)

def m3dRadToDeg(num):
    return (num * M3D_INV_PI_DIV_180)

# Translate matrix. Only 4x4 matrices supported
def m3dTranslateMatrix44(m, x, y, z):
    m[12] += x
    m[13] += y
    m[14] += z

# Creates a 4x4 rotation matrix, takes radians NOT degrees
def m3dRotationMatrix44(m, angle, x, y, z):
    s = math.sin(angle)
    c = math.cos(angle)
    mag = float((x * x + y * y + z * z) ** 0.5)

    if mag == 0.0:
        m3dLoadIdentity(m)
        return

    x /= mag
    y /= mag
    z /= mag

    xx = x * x
    yy = y * y
    zz = z * z
    xy = x * y
    yz = y * z
    zx = z * x
    xs = x * s
    ys = y * s
    zs = z * s
    one_c = 1.0 - c

    m[0] = (one_c * xx) + c
    m[1] = (one_c * xy) - zs
    m[2] = (one_c * zx) + ys
    m[3] = 0.0

    m[4] = (one_c * xy) + zs
    m[5] = (one_c * yy) + c
    m[6] = (one_c * yz) - xs
    m[7] = 0.0

    m[8] = (one_c * zx) - ys
    m[9] = (one_c * yz) + xs
    m[10] = (one_c * zz) + c
    m[11]  = 0.0

    m[12] = 0.0
    m[13] = 0.0
    m[14] = 0.0
    m[15] = 1.0

def m3dMultiply(A, B):
    C = (GLfloat * 16)(*identityMatrix)
    for k in range(0, 4):
        for j in range(0, 4):
            C[k*4+j] = A[0*4+j] * B[k*4+0] + A[1*4+j] * B[k*4+1] + \
                       A[2*4+j] * B[k*4+2] + A[3*4+j] * B[k*4+3]
    return C

def m3dOrtho(l, r, t, b, n, f):
    return (GLfloat * 16)(
        2/(r-l),      0,            0,            0,
        0,            2/(t-b),      0,            0,
        0,            0,            -2/(f-n),     0,
        -(r+l)/(r-l), -(t+b)/(t-b), -(f+n)/(f-n), 1)

def m3dPerspective(fov_y, aspect, n, f):
    a = aspect
    ta = math.tan( fov_y / 2 )
    return (GLfloat * 16)(
        1/(ta*a),  0,     0,              0,
        0,         1/ta,  0,              0,
        0,         0,    -(f+n)/(f-n),   -1,
        0,         0,    -2*f*n/(f-n),    0)

def rotation_matrix(axis, theta):
    """
    Return the rotation matrix associated with counterclockwise rotation about
    the given axis by theta radians.
    """
    axis = np.asarray(axis)
    axis = axis / math.sqrt(np.dot(axis, axis))
    a = math.cos(theta / 2.0)
    b, c, d = -axis * math.sin(theta / 2.0)
    aa, bb, cc, dd = a * a, b * b, c * c, d * d
    bc, ad, ac, ab, bd, cd = b * c, a * d, a * c, a * b, b * d, c * d
    return np.array([[aa + bb - cc - dd, 2 * (bc + ad), 2 * (bd - ac), 0],
                     [2 * (bc - ad), aa + cc - bb - dd, 2 * (cd + ab), 0],
                     [2 * (bd + ac), 2 * (cd - ab), aa + dd - bb - cc, 0],
                     [0,0,0,1]])

def translate(tx, ty, tz):
    """creates the matrix equivalent of glTranslate"""
    return np.array([1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 
                     0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 
                     0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 
                        tx, ty, tz, 1.0], np.float32)


def load_shaders():
        global render_prog
        global uniforms_mv_matrix
        global uniforms_proj_matrix

        if (render_prog):
            glDeleteProgram(render_prog);

        fs = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

        glShaderSource(fs, fs_source);
        glCompileShader(fs);

        vs = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);

        glShaderSource(vs, vs_source);
        glCompileShader(vs);

        render_prog = glCreateProgram();
        glAttachShader(render_prog, vs);
        glAttachShader(render_prog, fs);
        glLinkProgram(render_prog);

        glDeleteShader(vs);
        glDeleteShader(fs);

        uniforms_mv_matrix = glGetUniformLocation(render_prog, "mv_matrix");
        uniforms_proj_matrix = glGetUniformLocation(render_prog, "proj_matrix");


class Scene:
    def __init__(self, width, height):

        self.width = width
        self.height = height

        B = (0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00)
        W = (0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF)
        tex_data = [
            B, W, B, W, B, W, B, W, B, W, B, W, B, W, B, W,
            W, B, W, B, W, B, W, B, W, B, W, B, W, B, W, B,
            B, W, B, W, B, W, B, W, B, W, B, W, B, W, B, W,
            W, B, W, B, W, B, W, B, W, B, W, B, W, B, W, B,
            B, W, B, W, B, W, B, W, B, W, B, W, B, W, B, W,
            W, B, W, B, W, B, W, B, W, B, W, B, W, B, W, B,
            B, W, B, W, B, W, B, W, B, W, B, W, B, W, B, W,
            W, B, W, B, W, B, W, B, W, B, W, B, W, B, W, B,
            B, W, B, W, B, W, B, W, B, W, B, W, B, W, B, W,
            W, B, W, B, W, B, W, B, W, B, W, B, W, B, W, B,
            B, W, B, W, B, W, B, W, B, W, B, W, B, W, B, W,
            W, B, W, B, W, B, W, B, W, B, W, B, W, B, W, B,
            B, W, B, W, B, W, B, W, B, W, B, W, B, W, B, W,
            W, B, W, B, W, B, W, B, W, B, W, B, W, B, W, B,
            B, W, B, W, B, W, B, W, B, W, B, W, B, W, B, W,
            W, B, W, B, W, B, W, B, W, B, W, B, W, B, W, B,
        ]

        tex_object.append( glGenTextures(1) )

        #glGenTextures(1, tex_object[0]);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex_object[0]);
        glTexStorage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 1, GL_RGB8, 16, 16);
        glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, 16, 16, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, tex_data);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);

        tex_object.append (  glGenTextures(1) )

        #tex_object[1] = sb7::ktx::file::load("pattern1.ktx");

        myobject.load("torus_nrms_tc.sbm");

        load_shaders();

        glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);


    def display(self):

        global uniforms_mv_matrix
        global uniforms_proj_matrix

        currentTime = time.time()

        gray = [ 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 1.0 ];
        ones = [ 1.0 ];

        glClearBufferfv(GL_COLOR, 0, gray);
        glClearBufferfv(GL_DEPTH, 0, ones);

        glViewport(0, 0, self.width, self.height);

        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex_object[tex_index]);

        glUseProgram(render_prog);


        T = (GLfloat * 16)(*identityMatrix)
        RX = (GLfloat * 16)(*identityMatrix)
        RY = (GLfloat * 16)(*identityMatrix)
        R = (GLfloat * 16)(*identityMatrix)


        # way # 1 - works
        # T = translate(0.0, 0.0, -4.0).reshape(4,4)
        # RX = np.array(rotation_matrix( [1.0, 0.0, 0.0], currentTime * m3dDegToRad(17.0)))
        # RY = np.array(rotation_matrix( [0.0, 1.0, 0.0], currentTime * m3dDegToRad(13.0)))
        # mv_matrix = np.matmul(np.matmul(RY, RX), T)


        # way # 2 - works !!
        m3dTranslateMatrix44(T, 0, 0, -4)
        m3dRotationMatrix44(RX, currentTime * m3dDegToRad(17.0), 1.0, 0.0, 0.0)
        m3dRotationMatrix44(RY, currentTime * m3dDegToRad(13.0), 0.0, 1.0, 0.0)

        # way # 2 - option A   works!
        # Matrix multiplication is not commutative, order matters when multiplying matrices
        R = m3dMultiply(RY, RX) 
        mv_matrix = m3dMultiply(T, R)

        # way # 2 - option B    works!
        # T = np.matrix(T).reshape(4,4)
        # mv_matrix = np.matmul(np.matmul(np.matrix(RY).reshape(4,4), np.matrix(RX).reshape(4,4)).reshape(4,4), T)


        # way # 3 - works also
        # T  = np.matrix(translate(0.0, 0.0, -4.0)).reshape(4,4)
        # RX = np.matrix(rotation_matrix( [1.0, 0.0, 0.0], currentTime * m3dDegToRad(17.0)))
        # RY = np.matrix(rotation_matrix( [0.0, 1.0, 0.0], currentTime * m3dDegToRad(13.0)))
        # mv_matrix = RX * RY * T


        proj_matrix = (GLfloat * 16)(*identityMatrix)
        proj_matrix = m3dPerspective(m3dDegToRad(60.0), float(self.width) / float(self.height), 0.1, 100.0);    

        glUniformMatrix4fv(uniforms_mv_matrix, 1, GL_FALSE, mv_matrix);
        glUniformMatrix4fv(uniforms_proj_matrix, 1, GL_FALSE, proj_matrix);

        myobject.render()
        #gltDrawTorus(0.35, 0.15, 40, 20)

        glutSwapBuffers()

    def reshape(self, width, height):
        self.width = width
        self.height = height

    def keyboard(self, key, x, y ):
        global fullscreen
        global tex_index

        print ('key:' , key)
        if key == b'\x1b': # ESC
            sys.exit()

        elif key == b'f' or key == b'F': #fullscreen toggle

            if (fullscreen == True):
                glutReshapeWindow(self.width, self.height)
                glutPositionWindow(int((1360/2)-(512/2)), int((768/2)-(512/2)))
                fullscreen = False
            else:
                glutFullScreen()
                fullscreen = True

        elif key == b'r' or key == b'R': 
            load_shaders()

        elif key == b't' or key == b'T': 
            tex_index+=1
            if (tex_index > 1):
                tex_index = 0

        print('done')

    def init(self):
        pass

    def timer(self, blah):

        glutPostRedisplay()
        glutTimerFunc( int(1/60), self.timer, 0)
        time.sleep(1/20.0)

myobject = SBMObject()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    start = time.time()

    glutInit()
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_DEPTH)
    glutInitWindowSize(512, 512)
    w1 = glutCreateWindow('OpenGL SuperBible - Texture Coordinates')

    fullscreen = False
    #glutFullScreen()

    scene = Scene(512, 512)
    glutReshapeFunc(scene.reshape)
    glutDisplayFunc(scene.display)
    glutKeyboardFunc(scene.keyboard)

    glutIdleFunc(scene.display)
    #glutTimerFunc( int(1/60), scene.timer, 0)

    scene.init()

    glutMainLoop()
```

[image: Example of data structure of texture file - p.757 OpenGL Superbible 6th ed.]
Example of data structure of texture file - p.757 OpenGL Superbible 6th ed. or  p.807 7th ed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you are already using [NumPy](https://www.numpy.org/), i'll give yuo an answer which uses NumPy to read the binary file. NumPy has some had functionality to reinterpret buffer data by different data type and that is exactly what is needed to interpret a binary file.

A binary file can be read toe a byte array by [`numpy.fromfile`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fromfile.html).e.g.:

```py
data = numpy.fromfile(filename, dtype=np.byte)
```

Some bytes of the array can be interpreted as unsigned integer (`unit32`) by [`numpy.frombuffer`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.frombuffer.html). e.g.:

```py
class SB6M_HEADER:
    def __init__(self, data):
        int_data = np.frombuffer(np.array(data[:16], dtype=np.byte), dtype=np.uint32)
        self.magic, self.size, self.num_chunks, self.flags = int_data 
        print(self.magic, self.size, self.num_chunks, self.flags)
```

Porting the source code from [sb6mfile.h](https://github.com/openglsuperbible/sb7code/blob/master/include/sb6mfile.h) respectively [sb7object.cpp](https://github.com/openglsuperbible/sb7code/blob/3f80b7a829442e2de9199a15e08ce7d09fd9260e/src/sb7/sb7object.cpp#L47) to python and reading and "*.sbm" file:

```py
def SB6M_FOURCC(a,b,c,d):
    return ( (ord(a) << 0) | (ord(b) << 8) | (ord(c) << 16) | (ord(d) << 24) )

SB6M_MAGIC = SB6M_FOURCC('S','B','6','M')

SB6M_CHUNK_TYPE_INDEX_DATA      = SB6M_FOURCC('I','N','D','X')
SB6M_CHUNK_TYPE_VERTEX_DATA     = SB6M_FOURCC('V','R','T','X')
SB6M_CHUNK_TYPE_VERTEX_ATTRIBS  = SB6M_FOURCC('A','T','R','B')
SB6M_CHUNK_TYPE_SUB_OBJECT_LIST = SB6M_FOURCC('O','L','S','T')
SB6M_CHUNK_TYPE_COMMENT         = SB6M_FOURCC('C','M','N','T')
SB6M_CHUNK_TYPE_DATA            = SB6M_FOURCC('D','A','T','A')

class SB6M_HEADER:
    def __init__(self, data):
        int_data = np.frombuffer(np.array(data[:16], dtype=np.byte), dtype=np.uint32)
        self.magic, self.size, self.num_chunks, self.flags = int_data 
        print(self.magic, self.size, self.num_chunks, self.flags)

class SB6M_CHUNK_HEADER:
    def __init__(self, data, offset):
        int_data = np.frombuffer(np.array(data[offset:offset+8], dtype=np.byte), dtype=np.uint32)
        self.type, self.size = int_data

class SB6M_CHUNK_INDEX_DATA(SB6M_CHUNK_HEADER):
     def __init__(self, data, offset):
        super().__init__(data, offset)
        int_data = np.frombuffer(np.array(data[offset+8:offset+20], dtype=np.byte), dtype=np.uint32)
        self.index_type, self.index_count, self.index_data_offset = int_data

class SB6M_CHUNK_VERTEX_DATA(SB6M_CHUNK_HEADER):
     def __init__(self, data, offset):
        super().__init__(data, offset)
        int_data = np.frombuffer(np.array(data[offset+8:offset+20], dtype=np.byte), dtype=np.uint32)
        self.data_size, self.data_offset, self.total_vertices = int_data

class SB6M_CHUNK_VERTEX_DATA(SB6M_CHUNK_HEADER):
     def __init__(self, data, offset):
        super().__init__(data, offset)
        int_data = np.frombuffer(np.array(data[offset+8:offset+20], dtype=np.byte), dtype=np.uint32)
        self.data_size, self.data_offset, self.total_vertices = int_data

SB6M_VERTEX_ATTRIB_FLAG_NORMALIZED = 0x00000001
SB6M_VERTEX_ATTRIB_FLAG_INTEGER    = 0x00000002

class SB6M_VERTEX_ATTRIB_DECL:
    def __init__(self, data, offset):
        self.name = ''.join([chr(n) for n in data[offset:offset+64] if n > 30])
        int_data = np.frombuffer(np.array(data[offset+64:offset+84], dtype=np.byte), dtype=np.uint32)
        self.size, self.type, self.stride, self.flags, self.data_offset = int_data

class SB6M_VERTEX_ATTRIB_CHUNK(SB6M_CHUNK_HEADER):
    def __init__(self, data, offset):
        super().__init__(data, offset)
        int_data = np.frombuffer(np.array(data[offset+8:offset+12], dtype=np.byte), dtype=np.uint32)
        self.attrib_count = int_data[0]
        self.attrib_data = []
        for i in range(self.attrib_count):
            self.attrib_data.append(SB6M_VERTEX_ATTRIB_DECL(data, offset+12+i*84))

class SB6M_DATA_CHUNK(SB6M_CHUNK_HEADER):
    def __init__(self, data, offset):
        super().__init__(data, offset)
        int_data = np.frombuffer(np.array(data[offset+8:offset+20], dtype=np.byte), dtype=np.uint32)
        self.encoding, self.data_offset, self.data_length = int_data

class SB6M_SUB_OBJECT_DECL:
    def __init__(self, data, offset):
        int_data = np.frombuffer(np.array(data[offset:offset+8], dtype=np.byte), dtype=np.uint32)
        self.first, self.count = int_data

class SB6M_CHUNK_SUB_OBJECT_LIST(SB6M_CHUNK_HEADER):
    def __init__(self, data, offset):
        super().__init__(data, offset)
        int_data = np.frombuffer(np.array(data[offset+8:offset+12], dtype=np.byte), dtype=np.uint32)
        self.count = int_data[0]
        self.sub_object = []
        for i in range(self.count):
            self.sub_object.append(SB6M_SUB_OBJECT_DECL(data, offset+12+i*8))
```

```py
 def load(filename):

    vertex_attrib_chunk = None
    vertex_data_chunk = None
    index_data_chunk = None
    sub_object_chunk = None
    data_chunk = None

    try:
        data = numpy.fromfile(filename, dtype=np.byte)
        filesize = data.size

        header = SB6M_HEADER(data)
        offset = header.size

        for i in range(header.num_chunks):

            chunk = SB6M_CHUNK_HEADER(data, offset)
            if chunk.type == SB6M_CHUNK_TYPE_VERTEX_ATTRIBS:
                vertex_attrib_chunk = SB6M_VERTEX_ATTRIB_CHUNK(data, offset) 
            elif chunk.type == SB6M_CHUNK_TYPE_VERTEX_DATA:
                vertex_data_chunk = SB6M_CHUNK_VERTEX_DATA(data, offset)
            elif chunk.type == SB6M_CHUNK_TYPE_INDEX_DATA:
                index_data_chunk = SB6M_CHUNK_INDEX_DATA(data, offset) 
            elif chunk.type == SB6M_CHUNK_TYPE_SUB_OBJECT_LIST:
                sub_object_chunk = SB6M_CHUNK_SUB_OBJECT_LIST(data, offset)
            elif chunk.type == SB6M_CHUNK_TYPE_DATA:
                data_chunk = SB6M_DATA_CHUNK(data, offset) 
            else:
                raise

            offset += chunk.size

    except:
        print("error reading file {}".format(filename))
```

Finally the floating point vertex data can be read:

```py
if vertex_data_chunk and vertex_attrib_chunk:
    start = vertex_data_chunk.data_offset
    end = start + vertex_data_chunk.data_size
    vertex_data = np.frombuffer(np.array(data[start:end], dtype=np.byte), dtype=np.float)

    data_buffer = glGenBuffers(1)
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, data_buffer)
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertex_data, GL_STATIC_DRAW)

    vertexcount = vertex_data_chunk.total_vertices
    vao = glGenVertexArrays(1)
    glBindVertexArray(self.vao)

    for attrib_i, attrib in enumerate(vertex_attrib_chunk.attrib_data):
        if attrib.name=='position' or attrib.name=='map1':  
            glVertexAttribPointer(attrib_i,
                attrib.size, attrib.type,
                GL_TRUE if (attrib.flags & SB6M_VERTEX_ATTRIB_FLAG_NORMALIZED) != 0 else GL_FALSE,
                attrib.stride, ctypes.c_void_p(int(attrib.data_offset)))
            glEnableVertexAttribArray(attrib_i)
```

Finally draw the mesh:

```py
glBindVertexArray(vao)
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, vertexcount)
```

Answer (score 1):

The next step has to be similar to what happens in the [C code](https://github.com/openglsuperbible/sb7code/blob/3f80b7a829442e2de9199a15e08ce7d09fd9260e/src/sb7/sb7object.cpp#L64):

```
SB6M_HEADER * header = (SB6M_HEADER *)ptr;
ptr += header->size;
```

You need to advance the pointer by a known size.

You have that attribute in your header class. Do you set it correctly?

But I would suggest a different approach: do not use raw Pyhon for this at all.

Instead create a wrapper using the original C code found in [sb6mfile.h](https://github.com/openglsuperbible/sb7code/blob/master/include/sb6mfile.h)

and a part of the function to read the file found in [sb7object.cpp](https://github.com/openglsuperbible/sb7code/blob/3f80b7a829442e2de9199a15e08ce7d09fd9260e/src/sb7/sb7object.cpp#L47)

Then access this code using Python's [CFFI](https://cffi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/overview.html#main-mode-of-usage). You pass the C header with the SBM types
to the files and can use them in Python.

Once this works you can get the data back and put it in a numpy array. Usually this is a bit of work but once it works it is really robust.

Here are some links to get you started:

```
buffer_size = np_arr.size*np_arr.dtype.itemsize
c_buffer = ffi.buffer(cffi_arr,buffer_size)
np_arr2 = np.frombuffer(c_buffer, dtype=np_arr.dtype)
```

(https://ammous88.wordpress.com/2014/12/30/numpy-array-with-cffi-c-function/)

- https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.frombuffer.html
- [How to pass a Numpy array into a cffi function and how to get one back out?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16276268/how-to-pass-a-numpy-array-into-a-cffi-function-and-how-to-get-one-back-out)
- `numpy.frombuffer(ffi.buffer(p, size))` https://bitbucket.org/cffi/cffi/issues/292/cant-copy-data-to-a-numpy-array#comment-31752678