# Opengl in python and glut rendering incorrect results, any suggestions why?

Tags: python, opengl, glut

Referring to the reading of [OpenGL Superbible's SMB format file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56711138/how-to-read-parse-the-smb-file-format-from-superbible-opengl) where the source code is, I created a program with some help.  Now I am comparing the results to what I'm actually getting.

What I'm getting:
[image]

What the result should look like:
[image]

Any suggestions as to why the output is incorrect?  I'm stumped at this point.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The torus is clipped by the near plane of the projection.

Change the projection matrix:

```py
proj_matrix = m3dPerspective(m3dDegToRad(60.0), float(self.width) / float(self.height), 0.1, 100.0);
```

and the view matrix:

```py
mv_matrix = (GLfloat * 16)(*identityMatrix)
m3dRotationMatrix44(mv_matrix, currentTime * m3dDegToRad(45.0), 1.0, 0.0, 0.0)
m3dTranslateMatrix44(mv_matrix, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0)
```

---

If you want to concatenate different matrices, then you've to implement an matrix "multiplication":

```py
def m3dMultiply(A, B):
    C = (GLfloat * 16)(*identityMatrix)
    for k in range(0, 4):
        for j in range(0, 4):
            C[k*4+j] = A[0*4+j] * B[k*4+0] + A[1*4+j] * B[k*4+1] + \
                       A[2*4+j] * B[k*4+2] + A[3*4+j] * B[k*4+3]
    return C
```

e.g. Concatenate a translation matrix and the rotation matrices around x and y axis:

```py
T = (GLfloat * 16)(*identityMatrix)
m3dTranslateMatrix44(T, 0, 0, -4)

RX = (GLfloat * 16)(*identityMatrix)
m3dRotationMatrix44(RX, currentTime * m3dDegToRad(17.0), 1.0, 0.0, 0.0)

RY = (GLfloat * 16)(*identityMatrix)
m3dRotationMatrix44(RY, currentTime * m3dDegToRad(13.0), 0.0, 1.0, 0.0)

mv_matrix = m3dMultiply(T, m3dMultiply(RY, RX))
```

[image]

---

Note, if you want to use [`numpy.matmul`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.matmul.html) instead of `m3dMultiply`, then you've to [`.reshape`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) the 16 element array to a 2 dimensional 4x4 array. e.g.:

```py
R = np.matmul(np.array(RX).reshape(4,4), np.array(RY).reshape(4,4))
mv_matrix = np.matmul(R, np.array(T).reshape(4,4))
```

Or [`numpy.matrix`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.html) and the `*`-operator:

```py
mv_matrix = np.matrix(RX).reshape(4,4) * np.matrix(RY).reshape(4,4) * np.matrix(T).reshape(4,4)
```

See also [Python: How to get cube to spin and move in OpenGL Superbible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56696273/python-how-to-get-cube-to-spin-and-move-in-opengl-superbible-example)

Comment: Thank you so much!  Any idea on how to get it to also twist around the y axis while doing the current horizontal flip?

Comment: Incredible! Thanks.  The extended answer with the function m3dMultiply amazing.  I'm surprised there not a numpy solution to matrix multiply a 4x4 of either the a.dot(b) or np.matmul(a, b) based on my attempts it would not go for whatever reason.

Comment: @StanS. Of course you can use *numpy*, but you've to `.reshape()` to 4x4. See the last part of the answer.

Comment: @StanS. Hint: Do `glutInitWindowSize(512, 512)` before `glutCreateWindow`. Change to `scene = Scene(512, 512)` and add `def reshape(self, width, height):` `self.width = width` `self.height = height`

Comment: Excellent!  Having options with either your m3dMultiply or with numpy is awesome and I learn a lot seeing what numpy is actually doing when multiplying matrices.  Thank You.  Next I'll work on the pattern1.ktx loader of this project as a part 2 and again convert the code to python, seems ok for now.  Any questions I'll be sure to ask.

Comment: @StanS. Thank you. You're welcome. By the way, [this](https://pastebin.com/Etefk02B) is the current example code, which use.

Comment: Fantastic results!  I think this project could also benefit the community of programmers as well being that the format relatively new. TY